# XSS: Best way to encode href for anchor tags

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, security, security-review, xss

What would be the best way to sanitize a user input for href on anchor tags? I've been looking at this library that is created and approved by Salesforce ([SecureFilters](https://github.com/salesforce/secure-filters))

Looking at the different methods of the secureFilter library, I'm not sure which is relevant to encode href's. I did try secureFilters.js and secureFilter.uri, but this would escape the backslashes and colons which would not redirect properly.

an example of an href input would be https://google.com

js_encode = https\x3A\x2F\x2Fgoogle.com

uri_encode = https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

Any thoughts or help would be great.